# Can't get rid of "via" text for Twitter share button

Tags: twitter

I'm working in a Rails 3.1.8 app and I'm having a problem creating a Twitter share button that produces the text I want. Here is the erb code for the button:

`<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="<%= some_text %>" data-size="large" data-count="none" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>`

This button appears on a page that contains content produced by a particular user. Let's call the user "sam". The text this code produces to be shared on Twitter is:

> [some_text] [url of current page] via @sam

I would like to remove the "via @sam", but I cannot figure out how. If I explicitly set `data-via` I can change the user that the "via" phrase refers to, but I cannot make it disappear.

[This support page](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4168) suggests that omitting the `data-via` tag should do the trick, but I have found that it does not.

I've searched around the app to try to find a place where this parameter is being set, but I haven't found anything. However, as I'm pretty green with Twitter stuff, I may not be searching for the right thing.

Thanks in advance for your help, and do let me know if I can provide additional info.

ADDENDUM: I've tried add setting `data-via` to various values, including `false`, `"false"`, and `""`, as well as appending `?via=` and analogous values to the share URL. Each of these attempts resulted in a bogus via phrase (e.g. "@false"), or a default to "@sam".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an old version of the Javascript being included or cached.

Taking examples from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button works as expected when omitting the `data-via` attribute.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Isn't this great!?" data-lang="en" data-size="large" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

- Working example: http://jsbin.com/uxopur/2/

Comment: I had update that js previously and have ensured that it's running on the page, so I fear that this isn't the problem.

Comment: Both the docs and my example prove omitting `data-via` does what you're saying it does not when using the Javascript I've provided from the docs. Your question *(though you tagged it as such originally)* has nothing to do with Ruby on Rails, so why not create a standalone example through a tool like http://jsbin.com that shows the issue you're having.